# CSS element consuming entire width in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have an IE7 CSS issue. I have setup a demo in jsfiddle, but basically I have a tabbed menu setup with rounded corners on the tabs (no rounded corners shown in jsfiddle). The rounded corners are floated left and right.

Everything works great in FF and Chrome, but in IE7 the floated elements are causing the tabs to consume the entire width. I have tried numerous things, overflow: hidden, position, display, etc... but I just can't work it out!

Any help appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/EszSr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just set the corner elements to `display: absolute;` and the containers to `position: relative` if needed. That should work.

Simple demo on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZSpjk/1/

Comment: works well for the left corner, but the right corner not so well as there is a 2px gap (margin) to the right - I could factor in the 2px into the abs positioning but then the corners would only work for this content and I want to apply them to other content also

Comment: Sweet it works! Had played around with that a bit earlier, but must have done something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something that I'd try (don't have access to IE7 atm.) is, to give the tabs a width (only for IE, e.g. through a conditional comment). It could be a smaller width than you actually need, IE will "widen" it as needed for the content.